# Why does this sum give decimals? Jq + Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, rounding

I have the following code:

```
 console.log("1-"+parseFloat($('#pval').text().replace(',','.')));
 console.log("2-"+parseFloat($('#pvig').text().replace(',','.')));
 console.log("3-"+parseFloat($('#potr').text().replace(',','.')));
 var aux = parseFloat($('#pval').text().replace(',','.'))+parseFloat($('#pvig').text().replace(',','.'))+parseFloat($('#potr').text().replace(',','.'));
console.log("4-"+aux);
```

Which returns :

> 1-1.5
>
> 2-2.52
>
> 3-0.18
>
> 4-4.199999999999999 //<-This is the problem

Why is this simple sum, losing 0.000000000001 ? How should I repair it? I already tried 
`aux=Math.round(aux*100)/100;`

But itsn´t actually working.

Any help will be preciated.

---

### The values of those camps

id(pval)=1,5

id(pvig)=2,69

id(potr)=0,18

Comment: What are the text values of `pval`, `pvig` and `potr`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the question is editted with those camps added.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to fundamentally change it. if you have a new question, please ask it as a new question (feel free to reference your previous question if necessary).